# Mathematical modelling on Christofides algorithm

Tags: traveling-salesman

Does a mathematical modelling on Christofides algorithm exist, is it even possible to create one?

Comment: What is the "distribution problem" you are trying to solve?

Comment: Your question makes little sense I'm afraid. TSP is a problem with a precise input and output. You can say things like "I have a problem in which I need to distribute items to locations, and this problem can be modeled as an instance of TSP". But what is your question exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "a mathematical modelling on Christofides algorithm"? The algorithm has been analyzed mathematically: that's how we know that it works and know how long it takes.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Um. Christofides's original paper? Are you proposing that he just said, "Hey, here's this algorithm. I dunno if it works or anything, but you guys might find it interesting"? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm)?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen What do you mean by "a mathematical modelling"?

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical model relevant for understanding Christofides' algorithm is not the algorithm itself but rather the problem it is trying to solving – the traveling salesman problem. This is a model for optimization problems which occur in practice.

Christofides' algorithm itself could also perhaps be considered a model, if it is supposed to represent the way that humans (or animals, or nature) solve the traveling salesman problem. But in fact, it doesn't – it was designed as an efficient algorithm for computers.

Comment: No. What I’m saying is more like that 7 isn’t a color.

Comment: I think that’s the root of the problem. You seem to be trying to answer a questionable quiz question. Christofides’ algorithm is an *algorithm* or *heuristic*, not a model. It’s a category error to ask if it’s a mathematical model (though not completely out of the question, as I tried to explain in my answer). I don’t think your knowledge of mathematical modeling will be furthered by trying to answer nonsensical questions like this.

Comment: How about asking your TA or professor?

Comment: Complain to the dean. Unfortunately we cannot fix your university on this online platform.

Comment: In that case, your parents should contact the principal. We can’t fix the high school system online.